# Terraform dynamic resource name fr aws_kms_key

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I have to create a S3 bucket policy with KMS customer key encryption and append on coming change(adding accounts to KMS).

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "xxx-xx-xxxx-key-id" {
  description = "kms key append"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.kms_policy.json
}
```

I want to dynamically allocate the key-id as I run the same piece of code for multiple environments. How can we do it?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, the key-id of a kms key is always random, you cannot define it. If terraform creates a new key it ges a new id.

Comment: i'm not creating a new one, i'm appending.

Comment: What does appending mean in this context, there is no such thing as appending a key and there is no such thing as appending terraform. Do you mean that any time somebody comes along you edit the terraform file and add a new `resource "aws_kms_key" "..."` entry?

Comment: Or is the policy document supposed to contain a dynamic number of accounts to whitelist or should the resource be a `count` or `for_each` resource? You need to be a lot clearer in what your goal is, under what circumstance should what happen and why?

Comment: I am creating multiple accounts access one S3. With KMS encryption.
1) I create that setup once. Let's say I want to onboard a new account.
So I need to give the new account to access KMS key. So the second time I run I add the account number to existing KMS key.

Comment: Then your module should have an input variable `accounts_to_permit` which gets a list of all accounts that need access to the key and then your `data.aws_iam_policy_document.kms_policy` needs to use that variable.